# Palatini type gravities: Where could I find them?

Tags: gravity, resource-recommendations, quantum-gravity, modified-gravity

I read the article [Quantum gravity with torsion and non-metricity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02882). Although I found interesting the analysis in the paper, I found quite interesting an statement in the abstract,

> The class of actions we consider is of the Palatini type, including
>   the most general terms with up to two derivatives of the metric, but
>   no derivatives of the connection. It contains 19 independent
>   parameters.

Can someone provide a reference (or references) detailing the complete class of Palatini-like actions, and their 19 parameters?

Comment: Isn't the 19-parameter action actually in the paper?  The overall action is the sum of the Hilbert action (Eq. 19, with two parameters) and a quadratic term in the torsion & non-metricity tensors (Eq. 21 or 22 depending on how you write it, both having 17 parameters.)  If that's not sufficient, can you edit the question to further explain what you're looking for?